# Resume: Is it appropriate to say "xx years of proven software development experience"

Tags: resume, skills, software

I want to add this phrase to the "Skills" section of my resume.

Comment: Adding this phrase is asking them if you resume is correct? Is this the intention?

Comment: I want to know if this is a correct and good statement in a software engineer resume or no?

Comment: A resume is not for asking questions

Comment: That sounds like a marketing slogan for a contractor, not something on a resume.

Comment: What is the meaning you want to convey by "proven"?

Comment: As a statement, it's largely meaningless.  A future employer will want to know specifically what your skills are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say anything you like on a resume. As an interviewer this wouldn't mean much to me though. Not on it's own anyway, perhaps if it had references, but then you can just put in the references anyway.

Comment: Maybe it would work in the cover letter. Not in the resume, I think.

Comment: @keshlam I agree, I've seen some ridiculous things in resumes though.

Answer (score 0):

I would not think that would be a positive for most people reviewing resumes to determine who to interview because it proves nothing. If truly you have such proven skills show it with an accomplishments section or in the description of what you did in your individual job descriptions.